# Angular ng-model-options failing on IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a form submitted on `keypress/enter` using

```
ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"
```

Template:

```
<form ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" />    
...
```

This event is not captured on IE. I am testing on IE11

Any workaround for this?

Comment: please provide a plunker with reproducible problem statement in it..

Comment: It works fine. The issue was that I had `style="visibility:hidden;"` on the submit button, which behaved as `display:none` on IE

Answer (score 0):

Exchange `visibility` for `opacity` & `pointer-events`  :

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" style="opacity:0;pointer-events:none;" />
```